# My scss code does not parse in CSS with auto-prefix

Tags: webpack, autoprefixer

My `scss` code does not parse in `CSS` with auto-prefix. I use Webpack 4. I tried with this `postcss.config.js`.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                { loader: "css-loader", options: {} },
                {
                    loader: "postcss-loader",
                    options: {
                        ident: 'postcss',
                        plugins: [
                            require('autoprefixer')({
                                'browsers': ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions']
                            }),
                            require('cssnano')({ preset: 'default' })
                        ]
                    }
                },
                { loader: "sass-loader", options: {} }
            ]
        }

    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `importLoaders` option to `css-loader` to indicate that there are two other loaders preceeding it :

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 2 } },
                {
                    loader: "postcss-loader",
                    options: {
                        ident: 'postcss',
                        plugins: [
                            require('autoprefixer')({
                                'browsers': ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions']
                            }),
                            require('cssnano')({ preset: 'default' })
                        ]
                    }
                },
                { loader: "sass-loader", options: {} }
            ]
        }

    ]
},
```